# { "error_code": 1, "error_msg": "An unknown error occurred" } Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

When I try to pull out posts for the pages I manage, Facebook Graph API Explorer returns the following error:
{
  "error_code": 1, 
  "error_msg": "An unknown error occurred"
}

The requests worked fine until today. Do you have any idea what went wrong?
I am guessing this is a Facebook bug. Has anyone else encountered this>
The graph API request:
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/PAGEID/promotable_posts?is_published=false&limit=10&access_token=xxxxx
where 
xxxxxx is my access token with full permissions
PAGEID is the page id for the page.

Comment: Unless you can elaborate on what request this was then no.

Comment: Hi EWit, I added the Graph API request to my initial post. I also mention that I have full credentials for the pages, and these requests worked until today.

Comment: File a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs

Comment: Hi, I am having the same issue.. The same API throws this error to me on the /posts API and it is totally random. Strangely for page id 147482601960327, it will return posts when I specify limit less than or equal to 125 but when I specify a greater limit it returns with the above mentioned error. 
According to the facebook developer reference we can specify a limit of upto 250. 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.2/page/feed/
I am really looking for more insights on this.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error when requesting a limit of 200 on a /feed. I changed the code to detect an {"error_code":1} and reduce the limit by half until the call is successful.